# Rails, start remote debugger with an initializer only when --debugger is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I want to be able to use the rails remote debugger, I really like the notion of using a separate console over TTY to debug my application. Right now I have an initializer which does does this:

```
# debugger.rb

Debugger.wait_connection = true
Debugger.start_remote
```

Now the issue is that I don't know how to only run this initializer only when the `--debugger` parameter is sent when the server is started? Like how from inside my application can I evaluate this as `true`:

```
if '--debugger'
  Debugger.wait_connection = true
  Debugger.start_remote
end
```

Otherwise I have to start a remove console whenever the app boots, even for rake tasks and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if ARGV.include?('--debugger') || ARGV.include?('-u')
  Debugger.wait_connection = true
  Debugger.start_remote
end
```